# Visual C++ x86 ABI: how does VC++ return value?

Tags: visual-c++, x86, abi, x87, long-double

I know 1/2/4-byte integers are returned in `eax`, and 8-byte integers are returned in `eax:edx`.

By the way, how are 4/8/16-byte floating-point values <strike>(Maybe I remember `long double` might be 16 bytes..)</strike> returned in cdecl/stdcall?

---

Thanks to @MatteoItalia, I know that VC++'s `long double` is 8-byte; <strike>Then, how can I use 16-byte floating-point?</strike>

(Don't say me "just use 8 byte!". I really need it.)

Um, I think I should be satisfied with 10-byte floating point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FP return values are returned in the ST0 x87 register (see e.g. [here](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Floating_Point_Numbers#CDECL)).

By the way, in VC++ `long double` (which in x87 is 80 bit) is effectively a synonym for `double`.

Comment: @ikh: there's no native 128 bit FP support on x86 (or on any widespread platform that I know of), you probably have to look for some library that implements it in software (but it's going to be significantly slower than hardware-based FP). By the way, why do you need such a precise type?

Comment: @MetteoItalia um, I should be satisfied with 10 byte floating point.. I'm writing a tiny byte-code, interpreted language and there's some need for 16byte floating-point..., but I should use 10byte one as 16byte

Comment: @ikh: x87 does support 80 bit (=10 byte) FP, but VC++ does not expose this functionality. g++ OTOH does provide it (at least on Linux) via the type `long double`. I think that even in that case the return value will stay in ST0.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the architecture but x86 returns floating-point values in `ST(0)` and x86_64 return in `XMM0`. See [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

But `long double` in VC for x86 and x86_64 is [**the same as `double`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx) and won't provide you any more precision. So on Windows to do 80-bit floating-point operations you need to use another compiler such as [GCC, Clang or ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#Implementations). Also, 80-bit long double is calculated by x87 so it may perform worse than a good SSE library.

If you need more than 10-byte long double then you must implement your own floating-point library or use some external libraries. [GCC 4.3 and above](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) have built-in support for [`__float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) through a soft library. See [long double (GCC specific) and __float128](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13516476/995714)

Another approach is using [double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_%28arithmetic%29#Double-double_arithmetic) to implement *near-quadruple precision* values like in PowerPC or SPARC. It's not IEEE compatible but you can utilize hardware double suport to speedup so it'll be faster than soft `__float128`

Comment: Also on Windows, the MSVCRT code sets the x87 significand precision to 53-bit (`double`) before `main`, so if your GCC/Clang code is linked with that then you need to manually set it back to the default 64-bit significand full precision.  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/