# what is the difference between float128 and long double?

Tags: gcc

how is __float128 is defined by gcc.
what is the typedef.
128but numbers can be represented in different ways like,
double double,
char float128[16], or
int float128[4]

How is __float128 defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [long double (GCC specific) and \_\_float128](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516476/long-double-gcc-specific-and-float128)

Answer (score 0):

`long double` does not have a standardized format, in various implementations it could be a synonym to `double`, or 80-bit Intel format or quadruple-precision IEEE floating point format
or something else.

It GCC, `__float128` is [IEEE `binary128`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) on the amd64 and hp-pa.