# Performance benchmark of float128 type?

Tags: floating-point, performance-testing, arbitrary-precision

Has anyone experienced with `float128` type?

I would like to know about its performance compared with `double`, and other high precision types such as `boost::multiprecision:cpp_dec_float`? Is there any benchmark already done?

Comment: The `__float128` in gcc, at least on x86_64, [is a software quad-precision floating-point number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639477/what-exactly-is-a-float128-if-im-using-gcc-4-9-on-x86-64).  It's...not fast.  I'd switch to MPFR before using that thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `float128` is much slower than `double`. Like up to 100x slower but the precise slowdown would depend on the operations, of course.

[Multiplying two 256x256 matrices](https://www.nsc.liu.se/~pla/blog/2013/10/17/quadruple-precision/) is 100x slower.

The paper [Benchmark of an MPFR emulation of Binary128 arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/philippe.theveny/benchs/binary128_emu.pdf) cites 250x slowdown for summation, 120x slowdown for product, 400x slowdown for dot product.

Another paper [Twofolds in C and C++](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5316.pdf) says `__float128` summation is 150x (25x times 6x) slower than `double` summation.

Comment: Thanks for the data.