# Maximum Precision for C++ with Eigen3

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen, eigen3

I'm using the awesome Eigen3 library to write a MATLAB MEX file. But I am experiencing some accuracy issues (compared to MATLAB), even when using `long double`.
The most critical computation seems to be the one where I compute a probability according to the normal distribution. 
Here is the code snippet:

```
p.fill( 1/( M_PIl * sigma * sigma ) );
p.array() *= ( - 0.5/pow( sigma, 2.0 ) * ( mu.array() - x.array() ).array().square() ).array().exp();
```

where `x`, `p` and `mu` are `Eigen::Matrix< long double, Dynamic, 1 >`. Usually these vectors have a length of `3000`.

What are possible steps I can take to get the maximum possible precision?
What are the correct GCC compiler flags I can use to force 80 bit precision wherever possible?

P.S: I compile the C++ code (in MATLAB with MEX) with gcc 4.9 and my linux reports the following available instruction sets: Intel MMX, Intel SSE, Intel SSE2, Intel SSE3, Intel SSE4

Edit:
I tried what @Avi Ginsburg suggested below and compiled it using the following command:

```
mex -g -largeArrayDims '-I/usr/include/eigen3' CXXFLAGS='-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -std=c++11 -fPIC' test.cpp
```

with `double` and `long double` and each of these options gives me the same error with respect to the solution from MATLAB.

Comment: gcc will use 80-bit extended precision for `long double` on x86, no need for a flag. If you want more precision and can sacrifice performance then you can use [gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13516476/995714)'s [__float128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) type

Comment: `M_PI` does not have `long double` precision.  With GNU extensions you can use [`M_PIl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html#Mathematical-Constants), which has 128 bits of precision. That could be part of your problem.

Comment: What type(s) are `p`, `x`, and `mu`?

Comment: @AviGinsburg, thanks for your comment! I just updated the question with the information that all these are vectors of kind `Eigen::Matrix< long double, Dynamic, 1 >`.

Comment: Don't you need to suffix `l` or `L` for the literals? While they are probably upgraded to `long double` the precision may not be.

Comment: @AviGinsburg @mindriot I already tried it with `M_PIl` as also mindriot suggested but I didn't improve the error with respect to the MATLAB solution. I guess its because the separate line `p.fill( 1/( M_PIl * sigma * sigma ) );` is not that accuracy critical.

Comment: @bonanza I meant `0.5L` and `2.0L`. Also, change `pow(sigma, 2.0L)` to `sigma*sigma`.

Comment: Would be better if you provided source data (or how to generate it) and example codes for both Matlab and C++ version. Otherwise all the answers can only be guesswork. Also, what type does `sigma` have? How do you calculate/initialize it? It may just have too poor precision value at the very first step.

Comment: I agree with @Ruslan. It's time for a [mcve].

Comment: Please, also quantify the error you are observing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm hazarding a guess here. You are using SSE instructions with your array calculations, most notably, `...array().exp()`. I'm pretty sure there is no extended precision with SSE, hence the differences between MATLAB and Eigen.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way (e.g. using GCC compiler flags) to force FPU usage for these (or all) operations? Will this help in getting extended (e.g. 80 bit) precision?

Comment: No, Eigen was written with explicit vectorization (SSE) routines and doesn't rely on the compiler to recognize memory alignment and the vectorization opportunities. You can turn off Eigen's vectorization by defining `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`.

Comment: Just a comment, `sigma*sigma` will probably be faster than `pow( sigma, 2.0 )` (I know, insignificant compared to the rest of the line, but if sigma were an Eigen object, `sigma.square()` would be faster than `sigma.pow(2.0)` for the entire vector).

Comment: Does MATLAB use 80-bit precision? I doubt it very much. Most likely it uses native `double`, which is IEEE 754 `binary64` on x86.

Comment: I have no idea. Not my area of expertise. I assumed so based on the question but you have a very valid point. A quick search didn't yield any higher accuracy fp Matlab info.

Comment: @Ruslan I came up with [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94484-is-it-possible-to-use-extended-precision-for-decimal-number-using-64-bit-defined-by-ieee-754-standar). So natively, you are 100% correct, but arbitrary precision seems to be available as an add on.

Answer (score 1):

By default Eigen uses a faster but slightly less accurate implementation of several mathematical functions, including the exponential. You can explicitly disable these optimizations by compiling with the `-DEIGEN_FAST_MATH=0` option.

If you use gcc as your compiler also make sure that you don't use the `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math` options, as these can result in reduced precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the probability density of a (1 dimensional) [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), the factor at the beginning should be `1/std::sqrt( 2* M_PIl * sigma * sigma )`.

Also, the `p.fill()` at the beginning of your snippet is inefficient. Just write this in one line:

```
p = (1/std::sqrt(2*M_PIl*sigma*sigma)) *
      ( -0.5/(sigma*sigma) * (mu-x).array().square() ).exp();
```

N.B.: If you are only performing element-wise operations on your arrays, consider declaring them as `Eigen::Array<...>` instead of `Eigen::Matrix<...>`. The template parameters are the same, also the binary layout is the same, but you don't need to write `.array()` every time you want to make element-wise operations.