# Taylor Series in C (problem with sin(240) and sin(300))

Tags: c, taylor-series

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int TERMS = 7;
const float PI =  3.14159265358979;

int fact(int n) {
    return n<= 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n-1);
}


double sine(int x) {
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    double sin = 0;


    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) { // That's Taylor series!!
        sin += pow(-1, n) * pow(rad, (2 * n) + 1)/ fact((2 * n) + 1);
    }
    return sin;
}


double cosine(int x) {
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    double cos = 0;

    int n;

    for(n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) { // That's also Taylor series!
         cos += pow(-1, n) * pow(rad, 2 * n) / fact(2 * n);
    }
    return cos;
  }

int main(void){
   int y;
   scanf("%d",&y);
   printf("sine(%d)= %lf\n",y, sine(y));
   printf("cosine(%d)= %lf\n",y, cosine(y));

  return 0;
}
```

The code above was implemented to compute sine and cosine using Taylor series.
I tried testing the code and it works fine for sine(120).
I am getting wrong answers for sine(240) and sine(300).

Can anyone help me find out why those errors occur?

Comment: 7 isn't probably enough for 240 or 300. But you can't go farther with integer factorial unless you use long long

Comment: Note that [a POSIX-compliant system will define `M_PI` to the value of pi in `<math.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html#tag_13_26).

Comment: You should forget about degree conversions when doing mathematical analysis, and work "natively" in radians.

Comment: `pow` can be very bad too... you want to calculate the powers by just multiplying in the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You should calculate the functions in the first quadrant only [0, pi/2). Exploit the properties of the functions to get the values for other angles. For instance, for values of x between [pi/2, pi), sin(x) can be calculated by sin(pi - x).

The sine of 120 degrees, which is 40 past 90 degrees, is the same as 50 degrees: 40 degrees before 90. Sine starts at 0, then rises toward 1 at 90 degrees, and then falls again in a mirror image to zero at 180.

The negative sine values from pi to 2pi are just -sin(x - pi). I'd handle everything by this recursive definition:

```
sin(x):
  cases x of:
    [0, pi/2)   -> calculate (Taylor or whatever)
    [pi/2, pi)  -> sin(pi - x)
    [pi/2, 2pi) -> -sin(x - pi)
    < 0         -> sin(-x)
    >= 2pi      -> sin(fmod(x, 2pi))  // floating-point remainder
```

A similar approach for `cos`, using identity cases appropriate for it.

Comment: It is also a non-trivial issue that ther naive servies used in the OP's code is simply slow to converge. Chosing a faster converging series would help.

Comment: @dmckee, that's the reason for the recommendation made in this answer.  If you limit the absolute value of the angle below one radian, the convergence of the series is very quick, becoming slower as you depart from the origin value (in the case shown `0.0`)

Answer (score 2):

The key point is:

`TERMS` is too small to have proper precision. And if you increase `TERMS`, you have to change `fact` implementation as it will likely overflow when working with `int`.

I would use a sign to toggle the -1 power instead of `pow(-1,n)` overkill.

Then use `double` for the value of PI to avoid losing too many decimals

Then for high values, you should increase the number of terms (this is the main issue). using `long long` for your factorial method or you get overflow. I set 10 and get proper results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int TERMS = 10;
const double PI =  3.14159265358979;

long long fact(int n) {
    return n<= 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n-1);
}
double powd(double x,int n) {
    return n<= 0 ? 1 : x * powd(x,n-1);
}


double sine(int x) {
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    double sin = 0;


    int n;
    int sign = 1;
    for(n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) { // That's Taylor series!!
        sin += sign  * powd(rad, (2 * n) + 1)/ fact((2 * n) + 1);
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return sin;
}


double cosine(int x) {
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    double cos = 0;

    int n;
    int sign = 1;
    for(n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) { // That's also Taylor series!
         cos += sign * powd(rad, 2 * n) / fact(2 * n);
         sign = -sign;
    }
    return cos;
  }

int main(void){
   int y;
   scanf("%d",&y);
   printf("sine(%d)= %lf\n",y, sine(y));
   printf("cosine(%d)= %lf\n",y, cosine(y));

  return 0;
}
```

result:

```
240
sine(240)= -0.866026
cosine(240)= -0.500001
```

Notes:

- my recusive implementation of `pow` using successive multiplications is probably not needed, since we're dealing with floating point. It introduces accumulation error if n is big.
- `fact` could be using floating point to allow bigger numbers and better precision. Actually I suggested `long long` but it would be better not to assume that the size will be enough. Better use standard type like `int64_t` for that.
- `fact` and `pow` results could be pre-computed/hardcoded as well. This would save computation time.

Comment: Also, note some of the points brought up on this question and answers regarding greater floating-point precision:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516476/long-double-gcc-specific-and-float128

Comment: I think your changes are excessive (albeit likely improvements). The core problem with OP's code is the overflow in `fact`, and possibly also insufficient `TERMS`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My notes at the end of the answer explain that. The key point is : if TERMS is small then there's loss of precision, and if TERMS is >= 7 you get overflow unless you use int64_t or double. If you think you can edit the answer to make it more focused on the real issue, I see no issue with that.

Comment: The coefficients could be precomputed in their entirety too, not just fact.

Comment: true! an example where ideas of improvements came when writing the answer

Comment: Thanks for the all the help. I have implemented my own power function and changed the the fact function to return a long long and these changes solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
const double TERMS = 14;
const double PI = 3.14159265358979;

double fact(double n) {return n <= 0.0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);}

double sine(double x)
{
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    rad = fmod(rad, 2 * PI);
    double sin = 0;

    for (double n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) 
        sin += pow(-1, n) * pow(rad, (2 * n) + 1) / fact((2 * n) + 1);

    return sin;
}

double cosine(double x)
{
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    rad = fmod(rad,2*PI);
    double cos = 0;

    for (double n = 0; n < TERMS; n++)
        cos += pow(-1, n) * pow(rad, 2 * n) / fact(2 * n);

    return cos;
}

 int main()
{

    printf("sine(240)= %lf\n",  sine(240));
    printf("cosine(300)= %lf\n",cosine(300));
}
```